# ScriptManager - AsyncPostBackTimeout to "0"

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

I have designed a report in report builder 3.0 using dataset which is using store procedure from sql server 2008 r2. It works fine if i pull less information from database but if i try to pull large information then i get 'The Operation has Timed Out' message in report builder.

I am showing this report in VS2012 using report viewer but i am getting following error message on pulling large information from database.

```
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.
```

I have google this issue and came across following article;

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2012/06/18/reportviewer-2010-control-fails-with-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagertimeoutexception-the-server-request-timed-out.aspx

After setting script manager property **AsyncPostBackTimeout to "0"**, report works fine.

In my project Script Manager control is in master page, i am just wondering if setting AsyncPostBackTimeout to 0 in master page would cause any issues?